HTMX cannot find element on site
I'm trying to build a webapp with django and htmx. One of the functionalities with htmx is that I want to dynamically insert rows into a table. For that I have...
a base.html file:
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap 5-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" defer></script>

    <!-- HTMX -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/htmx.min.js' %}" defer></script>
    
    <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/svg" href="{% static 'favicon.svg' %}"/>

        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}

        <div class="container-fluid">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <strong>Holy guacamole! {{ message }}</strong>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

an "add-periods.html" file:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="container-fluid shadow p-4 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
        
            <h3 class="pt-5 text-center">Zeiträume für die Abrechnung erfassen</h3>
            <h5 class="text-secondary text-center">{{ patient.first_name }} {{ patient.last_name }}, geb. {{ patient.birthday|date:'d.m.Y' }}</h5>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h6 class="text-secondary"> Ein paar schnelle Tipps:</h6>
                        <ul class="text-secondary list-unstyled">
                            <li>Eine leere Zeile abschicken -> Diesen Zustand für die gesamte Betreuung verwenden (zB dauerhafter Heimaufenthalt)</li>
                            <li>Nur ein Anfangsdatum eintragen -> Von diesem Datum an dauerhaft diesen Zustand verwenden (zB Einzugsdatum ins Heim)</li>
                            <li>Nur ein Enddatum eintragen -> Nur bis zu diesem Zeitpunkt (zB war der/die Betreute vermögend bis zum Datum X)</li>
                            <li>Anfangs- und Enddatum eintragen -> Zustand von/bis (zB war vom X bis zum Y ein Vermögen von mehr als 150.000 EUR vorhanden)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col mx-5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-primary h5">
                                <th colspan="4">Heimaufenthalte des Betreuten</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-primary d-flex">
                                <th class="col-4">Von</th>
                                <th class="col-4">Bis</th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% include 'partials/nursinghome-tbody.html' %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col mx-5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-primary h5">
                                <th colspan="4">Zeiträume, in denen der Betreute vermögend war</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-primary d-flex">
                                <th class="col-4">Von</th>
                                <th class="col-4">Bis</th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% include 'partials/wealthy-tbody.html' %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row m-5 p-5">

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col mx-5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-primary h5">
                                <th colspan="4">Zeiträume mit Verwaltung eines Erwerbsgeschäfts</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-primary d-flex">
                                <th class="col-4">Von</th>
                                <th class="col-4">Bis</th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% include 'partials/business-tbody.html' %}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col mx-5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-primary h5">
                                <th colspan="4">Zeiträume mit Geldvermögen über 150.000€</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-primary d-flex">
                                <th class="col-4">Von</th>
                                <th class="col-4">Bis</th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% include 'partials/wealthy150k-tbody.html' %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-5 p-5">

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col mx-5">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-primary h5">
                                <th colspan="4">Zeiträume mit Verwaltung nicht selbst bewohnter Immobilien</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-primary d-flex">
                                <th class="col-4">Von</th>
                                <th class="col-4">Bis</th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                                <th class="col-2"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% include 'partials/landlord-tbody.html' %}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col mx-5">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="container-xl shadow p-4 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
            <center>
                <img src="/static/buckingham_guard.png" class="mb-5">

                <h1>Sorry, Sie müssen angemeldet sein um diese Seite aufzurufen</h1>
                <br>
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Zur Anmeldung</a>
            </center>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}

and some partials. I'm only showing the nursinghome period realted partials here but the others are exactly the same except the variable names:
nursinghome-tbody.html:
{% for nursinghome_period in patient.nursinghome_periods.all %}
    {% include 'partials/nursinghome-period.html' %}
{% endfor %}

{% include 'partials/nursinghomeform.html' %}

nursinghome-period.html:
{% if not nursinghome_period.start_date and not nursinghome_period.end_date %}
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-8" colspan="2">Dauerhafter Heimaufenthalt</td>
        <td class="col-2"></td>
        <td class="col-2">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    hx-get="{% url 'del-nursinghome-period' nursinghome_period.id %}"
                    hx-target="closest tr"
            >
                Löschen
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% else %}
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-4">{{ nursinghome_period.start_date|date:"d.m.Y" }}</td>
        <td class="col-4">{{ nursinghome_period.end_date|date:"d.m.Y" }}</td>
        <td class="col-2"></td>
        <td class="col-2">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    hx-get="{% url 'del-nursinghome-period' nursinghome_period.id %}"
                    hx-target="closest tr"
            >
                Löschen
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}

and nursinghomeform.html:
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<tr class="table-light d-flex">
    <form
        hx-post="{% url 'add-nursinghome-period' patient.id %}"
        hx-target="closest tbody"
        hx-ext="debug"
    >
        <div class="container">
            <td class="col col-4">{% render_field nursinghomeform.start_date type='date' id='start-date' class+='form-control' %}</td>
            <td class="col col-4">{% render_field nursinghomeform.end_date type='date' id='end-date' class+='form-control' %}</td>
            <td class="col col-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">
                    Zeitraum hinzufügen
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="col col-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"
                        hx-target="closest tr"
                        hx-swap="outerHTML"
                        hx-get="{% url 'add-nursinghome-period' patient.id %}"
                >
                    Abbrechen
                </button>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</form>

and here is the relevant django view:
def add_nursinghome_period(request, patient_id):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(id=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NursingHomeForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            nursinghome_period = form.save(commit=False)
            nursinghome_period.patient = patient
            nursinghome_period.save()
            nursinghomeform = NursingHomeForm()
            context = {"patient": patient, "nursinghomeform": nursinghomeform}
            return render(request, "partials/nursinghome-tbody.html", context)

    context = {"nursinghomeform": NursingHomeForm, "patient": patient}
    return render(request, "partials/nursinghomeform.html", context)

Expected behavior:

When the website is rendered, the is a table that shows all the already entered nursinghome periods (works)
When I click on the delete button of any of those, the period shall be deleted from the database and the line be removed from the table via htmx (works)
When I enter numbers into the form at the bottom of the table and mess up, a click on the cancel button shall remove that form and replace it with a new one via htmx (does not work)
When I Submit the form, the period shall be saved in the database and a new tbody shall be inserted containing all periods, the form and so forth (does not work)

What I tried:
I used the browser devtools. I can see in chrome and firefox devtools that when I click the button, a new form / tbody is sent. But it is not inserted into the DOM, instead htmx tells me it did not find the next tbody.
When I enter htmx.logAll() into the console to understand what's happening, I get an error message that htmx is undefined (WTF? It's there and partially working, how can it not be defined?)
When I try to use the debug extension - Same result, htmx is not defined.
I looked at a previous version of the code (when the htmx worked as expected) and did not find any differences in the html between the working version and the non-working version... So again, WTF?!
I've been searching the bug now for two days, so I'm getting a little frustrated. Does anybody have a hint as to why this is not working as expected, why it suddenly stopped working and what I need to change to make it work?
Almost forgot this... No, I have not updated to version 2 of HTMX, so this cannot be the problem.
Greetings
André

In the context you're returning when the form is invalid (when you mess up) or with a GET request, you are referencing NursingHomeForm but it not defined anywhere in that view. I'm sure if you take a look at the server you will see an error.

"tells me it did not find the next tbody" Should we assume you mean closest tbody? It is important to be hyper-precise about these things in the problem description because you can in fact also target a 'next' element.
